# Installing Bioconductor without Internet

Tags: r, installation, bioconductor

I am working on a station where communication by internet is forbiden. Is it possible to install Bioconductor with R CMD INSTALL ? This type of installation is not documented on the Bioconductor web site, and I did not found any information on this topic.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative answer was [given by Kasper Daniel Hansen on the BioC mailing list](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/bioconductor/2012-December/049638.html) (see also [the final code](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/bioconductor/2012-December/049645.html)). The idea is to install `BiocInstaller` on a machine that has Internet access to download the packages on a disk, and then install them in the right order on the machine without Internet access.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do that is to install the packages on a machine of the same type (same R version, architecture (32/64bits), OS), and copy the library to the other machine. Have a look at [R's Add-on documentation](http://www.cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#Add_002don-packages) to see where your library is stored.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a Bioconductor mirror at your institution:

http://www.bioconductor.org/about/mirrors/mirror-how-to/

Answer (score 0):

I emailed the folks at Bioconductor about installing the RBGL package without Internet and got a quick and helpful response. So I thought I would share:

> Using a modified version of the technique described here:
>   [Listing R Package Dependencies Without Installing Packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14645363/listing-r-package-dependencies-without-installing-packages)
>
> You can end up with a list of all the packages you need in order to
>   run RBGL and graph (the recursive dependencies). This turns out to be
>   RGBL and graph themselves plus one additional package, BiocGenerics.
>
> You can download these packages from their package landing page, e.g.
>   for BiocGenerics:
>
> http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/BiocGenerics.html
>
> This assumes you are running R 3.0.x and will be using Bioconductor
>   2.13. If you're using a different version of Bioconductor, change the 'release' in the URL above to match its version number.
>
> From the 'Package Downloads' section of this page, install the
>   appropriate version of the package. Do this for graph and RBGL and
>   well, copy the three files to the target machine and there run (in
>   this order) R CMD INSTALL BiocGenerics_* R CMD INSTALL graph_* R CMD
>   INSTALL RBGL_*
>
> Then you should be set.
>
> Another thing to consider is hosting a mirror of Bioconductor inside
>   your institution's firewall (you'd need to host a CRAN mirror as
>   well). This is a lot of work just to install a couple of packages,
>   though.

Some of this is specific to the RBGL package, but there's enough information here for this to be generally useful to anyone trying to install Bioconductor packages.