# Determine minimum R version for all package dependencies

Tags: r, package

I am a package developer and want to state the minimum R version required to use my package in the `DESCRIPTION` file.

`available.packages` parses DESCRIPTIONS of packages, but the result is not (easily) machine readable to lookup recursive dependencies, since the Imports and Depends fields are comma separated text, and sometimes contain packages have version requirements.

The solution described in:
[Listing R Package Dependencies Without Installing Packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14645363/listing-r-package-dependencies-without-installing-packages) is not a recursive solution. If a nested dependency needed R > 3.3, I want to know about it.

At a minimum, I would like to see the minimum version of R and imported, linked, and depends packages for a given CRAN package. Better still would be to list the package or packages which set the minimum R or package version.

By eliminating dependencies which have higher version requirements, I can serve more people with institutionally old R versions they can't fix: some are still on R 2.x.

Comment: I doubt you will recruit substantial interest in this project, but one method might be to first check the dates of R versions and then not install any packages with later dates. (It won't be an R script.) You will need to ensure that an appropriate set of build tools are available for the particular version of R and the particular OS, since there is no comprehensive store of binary packages. An alternate might be to determine the reasons for useRs being backward and fix those problems.

Comment: And the second answer to that cited question did offer a recursive solution. So maybe this is a duplicate (even if the checkmarked solution was to totally satisfactory)? I'll hold of marking as a duplicate but may do so unless the question is edited to include a more complete description of the requirements.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is fraught w/potential peril. You've got packages like [`rodham`](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/rodham/) that _claim_ >= 2.1.0 but _actually_ needs >= 3.2.0 due to the use of a function (`trimws()`) that was introduced in 3.2.0 and isn't available in 2.1.0. Since it was introduced into CRAN after 3.2.0 was out and the CRAN tests are only with current and devel versions, it'll miss this dependency error.  I suspect you'd be better off building a set of docker images with each R version & running your pkg tests against them to determine min version. Very automatable.

Comment: Ah, I had naively assumed that packages would tend to state their R dependency correctly, or possibly give unnecessarily high versions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
min_r_version <- function(package="ggplot2", exclude_main_pkg=TRUE) {

  purrr::walk(c("tools", "purrr", "devtools", "stringi", "tidyr", "dplyr"), 
              require, character.only=TRUE)

  deps <- package_dependencies(package, recursive=TRUE)

  if (exclude_main_pkg) {
    pkgs <- deps[[1]]
  } else {
    pkgs <- c(package, deps[[1]])
  }

  available.packages() %>% 
    as_data_frame() %>% 
    filter(Package %in% pkgs) %>% 
    select(Depends)  %>% 
    unlist() -> pkg_list

  # if main pkg only relied on core R packages (i.e. pkgs that aren't in CRAN) and we 
  # excluded the pkg itself from the min version calculation, this is an edge case we need
  # to handle.

  if (length(pkg_list) == 0) return("Unspecified")

  stri_split_regex(pkg_list, "[,]") %>%
    unlist() %>%
    trimws() %>%
    stri_match_all_regex(c("^R$|^R \\(.*\\)$")) %>%
    unlist() %>%
    discard(is.na(.)) %>%
    unique() %>%
    stri_replace_all_regex("[R >=\\(\\)]", "") %>%
    data_frame(vs=.) %>%
    separate(vs, c("a", "b", "c"), fill="right") %>%
    mutate(c=ifelse(is.na(c), 0, c)) %>%
    arrange(a, b, c) %>%
    tail(1) %>%
    unite(min, a:c, sep=".") -> vs

  return(vs$min)

}

# did we handle the edge cases well enought?
base <- c("base", "compiler", "datasets", "grDevices", "graphics", "grid", "methods", "parallel", "profile", "splines", "stats", "stats4", "tcltk", "tools", "translations")
(base_reqs <- purrr::map_chr(base, min_r_version))
##  [1] "Unspecified" "Unspecified" "Unspecified" "Unspecified" "Unspecified"
##  [6] "Unspecified" "Unspecified" "Unspecified" "Unspecified" "Unspecified"
## [11] "Unspecified" "Unspecified" "Unspecified" "Unspecified" "Unspecified"

# a few of the "core" contributed pkgs rely on a pkg or two outside of base
# but many only rely on base packages, to this is another gd edge case to
# text for.
contrib <- c("KernSmooth", "MASS", "Matrix", "boot", "class", "cluster", "codetools", "foreign", "lattice", "mgcv", "nlme", "nnet", "rpart", "spatial", "survival")
contrib_reqs <- purrr::map_chr(contrib, min_r_version)
##  [1] "Unspecified" "Unspecified" "3.0.0"       "Unspecified" "3.1.0"      
##  [6] "Unspecified" "Unspecified" "Unspecified" "Unspecified" "3.0.2"      
## [11] "3.0.0"       "Unspecified" "Unspecified" "Unspecified" "3.0.1"      

# See what the min version of R shld be for some of my pkgs
min_r_version("ggalt") # I claim R (>= 3.0.0) in DESCRIPTION
## [1] "3.1.2"

min_r_version("curlconverter") # I claim R (>= 3.0.0) in DESCRIPTION
## [1] "3.1.2"

min_r_version("iptools") # I claim R (>= 3.0.0) in DESCRIPTION
## [1] "3.0.0"
```

Comment: Wow. Great, thanks. Does this exclude the R requirement of the queried package itself, since this is the variable we want to change?

Comment: right now, it includes it since there needs to be some `if-else` logic to deal with certain edge cases if we exclude it, but this is the core logic of the process.

Comment: The updated function supports excluding the specified pkg and handles said edge case. There may be other edge cases I'm not thinking of.

Answer (score 1):

Based on ideas from @hrbrmstr and written with base functions, I'm now using the following function:

```
min_r_version <- function(pkg, repo = "http://cloud.r-project.org") {
  requireNamespace("tools")
  requireNamespace("utils")
  if (is.null(repo))
    repo <- "https://cloud.r-project.org"
  repo <- getOption("repos", default = repo)
  avail <- utils::available.packages(utils::contrib.url(repos = repo))
  deps <- tools::package_dependencies(pkg, db = avail, recursive = TRUE)
  if (is.null(deps))
    stop("package not found")
  
  pkgs <- deps[[1]]
  
  matches <- avail[ , "Package"] %in% pkgs
  pkg_list <- avail[matches, "Depends"]
  vers <- grep("^R$|^R \\(.*\\)$", pkg_list, value = TRUE)
  vers <- gsub("[^0-9.]", "", vers)
  if (length(vers) == 0)
    return("Not specified")
  
  max_ver = vers[1]
  if (length(vers) == 1)
    return(max_ver)
  
  for (v in 2:length(vers))
    if (utils::compareVersion(vers[v], max_ver) > 0)
      max_ver <- vers[v]
  
  max_ver
}
```

Comment: Sorry to exhume this, but I suggest correcting the function. When running on a _tabula rasa_, the function does not know what the object `repo` is when assigning the `avail` object.