# Does DESCRIPTION file in an R package need an Imports value referring to an R base version?

Tags: r

I am planning on using this function `trimws` but I have read here ([How to trim leading and trailing whitespace in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261079/how-to-trim-leading-and-trailing-whitespace-in-r)) that it is a relatively recent addition to `R base` (`>=3.2.0`).

Does this mean that if I use `trimws` in a package I should enforce the requirement R base version greater or equal than `3.2.0`?

In general, do you check for every `R base` function you use when it was introduced, and if recent, you use an `Imports` value in `DESCRIPTION` to account for that?

Comment: If you're using `trimws()` you definitely have that version of R as a dependency and should include it. I generally do the legwork to determine the base R version required, but that's often pretty easy for me as I usually depend on other packages (not just base R) and they generally have their base versions of R required listed. I've answered a couple questions on SO in the past few weeks that cover how to do this recursively. But I wish there was a list maintained somewhere on CRAN that has what new functions were added or changed in each version (in JSON or something similar).

Comment: In general, every package is updated but it has a minimum dependency. The package documentation from cran provides the details. Some packages also require additional packages. I mostly install each package with all of its dependencies to be safe. But if you want to read all updates that come out, I would suggest going here: https://journal.r-project.org/

Comment: @hrbrmstr: Thank you for you comment. Could you post the links to these other answers you have given regarding this?

Comment: Caught me being lazy ;-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38686427/determine-minimum-r-version-for-all-package-dependencies/38687310#38687310 & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38738292/how-can-i-automatically-add-update-depends-imports-suggests-versions-in-descript/38743324#38743324

Comment: You can also conditionally import functions, based on OS, R version, etc. If this is an essential function, add an R version requirement; if not, have no R version dependency in DESCRIPTION, conditionally import the function in NAMESPACE, and have your pkg issue an error on older R versions.

Comment: @hrbrmstr: care to answer so that we can give this question some closure?