# format R package dependency strings

Tags: r

Goal: List all package names of a certain package - here: "ggplot2"

Desired Output:

```
c(digest, grDevices, grid, gtable, lazyeval, MASS, mgcv, reshape2, rlang, scales, stats, tibble, viridisLite, withr)
```

I get very Close with:

```
pack <- available.packages()
p <- pack["ggplot2", c("Imports")]
p
"digest, grDevices, grid, gtable (>= 0.1.1), lazyeval, MASS,\nmgcv, reshape2, rlang (>= 0.3.0), scales (>= 0.5.0), stats,\ntibble, viridisLite, withr (>= 2.0.0)"
```

See here: [Listing R Package Dependencies Without Installing Packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14645363/listing-r-package-dependencies-without-installing-packages).

Next i want to replace the Version number, e.g. "(>= 2.0.0)"

What i tried:

```
library(stringr)
res <- str_match_all(p, " ( (.*?) )")
res <- str_match_all(p, " [(] (.*?) [)]")
```

Comment: Bit unclear... What is your expected output for the case of `ggplot2`?

Comment: You can use gtools for that like this, If I understood you properly, `gtools::getDependencies('ggplot2')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `stringr` you could split the string and remove anything inside parentheses (inclusive), spaces, and newlines:

```
library(stringr)

str_remove_all(str_split(p, ",")[[1]], "\\(.*\\)|\\\n|\\s+")
[1] "digest"      "grDevices"   "grid"        "gtable"      "lazyeval"    "MASS"        "mgcv"        "reshape2"    "rlang"      
[10] "scales"      "stats"       "tibble"      "viridisLite" "withr"
```

Same logic with base R:

```
gsub("\\(.*\\)|\\\n|\\s+", "", strsplit(p, ",", fixed = T)[[1]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `gsub`

```
gsub("\\(>= \\d\\.\\d\\.\\d\\)", "", p)
#[1] "digest, grDevices, grid, gtable , lazyeval, MASS,\nmgcv, reshape2, rlang , 
#      scales , stats,\ntibble, viridisLite, withr "
```

But this returns output as a single string, if you want it as character vector we can split the strings on comma

```
strsplit(gsub("\\(>= \\d\\.\\d\\.\\d\\)", "", p), ",")[[1]]

#[1] "digest"  " grDevices"   " grid"  " gtable"  " lazyeval"  " MASS"       
#[7] "\nmgcv"  " reshape2"    " rlang"       " scales"      " stats"  "\ntibble"    
#[13] " viridisLite" " withr"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use *gsub()* combined with *lapply()* as follows:

```
res = unlist(lapply(p, function (i) gsub("\\(>= \\d\\.\\d\\.\\d\\)", '',i)))
```

This will give the following output which is **p** without the versions:

```
> res
[1] "digest, grDevices, grid, gtable , lazyeval, MASS,\nmgcv, reshape2, rlang , scales , stats,\ntibble, viridisLite, withr "
> p
[1] "digest, grDevices, grid, gtable (>= 0.1.1), lazyeval, MASS,\nmgcv, reshape2, rlang (>= 0.3.0), scales (>= 0.5.0), stats,\ntibble, viridisLite, withr (>= 2.0.0)"
```