# Recursively checking for R package dependencies

Tags: r, package, dependency-management, cran

I maintain a small R package but the question is more generalizable to understanding what packages are "required" to run some arbitrary function.  I became interested when my package started failing `rhub` checks for the devel branch.  Reporting that `data.table` was unavailable.  That didn't concern me too much I'm sure they'll address that.  **BUT** I don't import, suggest or enhance that package so why was I failing.  Obviously some other package needed it.  Manually trying to comb through description files was labor intensive and quite frankly fruitless.

I went looking and found `miniCRAN` which seems to get me quite a bit of the way there.  A little `purrr` magic and I can feed it a list of packages I do need and see what comes back.  **I was actually very surprised** comparing description files to my results I would have never known.

My question is, am I missing something obvious?  Is there a faster more efficient way to answer this sort of question in the future? Thank you.

```r
library(miniCRAN)
library(purrr)
package_list <- c("BayesFactor",
"broom",
"car",
"DescTools",
"dplyr",
"forcats",
"ggmosaic",
"ggplot2",
"ggrepel",
"paletteer",
"partykit",
"purrr",
"rlang",
"sjstats",
"stringr",
"tidyr")

names(package_list) <- package_list

purrr::map(package_list, ~ grep(pattern = "data.table", 
                                value = TRUE, 
                                x = pkgDep(., 
                                           includeBasePkgs = FALSE,
                                           suggests = TRUE,
                                           enhances = FALSE)
                                )
           )

#> $BayesFactor
#> character(0)
#> 
#> $broom
#> [1] "data.table"
#> 
#> $car
#> [1] "data.table"
#> 
#> $DescTools
#> character(0)
#> 
#> $dplyr
#> character(0)
#> 
#> $forcats
#> character(0)
#> 
#> $ggmosaic
#> [1] "data.table"
#> 
#> $ggplot2
#> [1] "data.table"
#> 
#> $ggrepel
#> character(0)
#> 
#> $paletteer
#> character(0)
#> 
#> $partykit
#> [1] "data.table"
#> 
#> $purrr
#> character(0)
#> 
#> $rlang
#> character(0)
#> 
#> $sjstats
#> [1] "data.table"
#> 
#> $stringr
#> character(0)
#> 
#> $tidyr
#> character(0)
```

Comment: I might be dense here, but what is the actual question? Are you for some reason not happy with miniCRAN?

Comment: This was perhaps already answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/48645545/13513328

Comment: Thank you @Waldi I'll check it out I didn't see it pop up in my searches.

Comment: Hi @Roland I tried to make the question obvious, "My question is, am I missing something obvious? Is there a faster more efficient way to answer this sort of question in the future?"  No I'm not "unhappy" with `miniCRAN` just wondering if there was a better or easier or base solution.

Comment: I did check @Waldi and the previous answer you mentioned definitely does not have a viable recursive solution although it does have some nice answers for non recursive cases.